# Override anonymous function argument in php

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, anonymous-function, anonymous-types

I have a little problem with an anonymous function in php. This function is performed by the framework, which pass variable there. I would like to override this variable without changing framework the code, is it possible in php?
Here code explaining what's going on. Freamwork code:

```
protected function callMessageBuilder($callback, $message)
{
    if ($callback instanceof Closure)
    {
        return call_user_func($callback, $message);
    }
}
```

Here is my code with an anonymous function with variable  $message passed by freamwork. I'd like to replace it with previously prepared variable.

```
public function sendEmail(){
    $ourMessage = $this->getMessage();
    \Mail::send($this->getTemplate(), $this->getData(), function ($message) use ($ourMessage) {
        $message = $ourMessage;
        //This change is not visible in freamwork code callback
    });
}
```

I knew how to do it rewriting the freamwork code so that it uses references but I want to avoid that. Is there any solution? Here is the entire code of this class from freamwork Here is the entire code from freamwork: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Mail/Mailer.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you have already a **$message** object that you'd like that object to be used within **Mailer::send()** method instead of the object that gets created in **Mailer::send()** with **$this->createMessage()**

There is no way to make the external **$message** reference point to some other object as what your callback gets is a copy of the reference. You can, however, modify the object that is referenced by **$message** so that it is identical to **$ourMessage**. Pass your message to the closure like you do already, and then instead of doing

```
$message = $ourMessage;
```

copy whatever you have set for **$ourMessage** to **$message** object. Even though you won't replace **$message** with **$ourMessage**, you will make the objects identical.

Comment: I thought about it too. However setters in Message class cause changes in variables. Referring to their getter functions we will recive already modified data. Writing such replacer seems to take a lot of work. I think there is no other possibility without rewriting code of freamwork. So bad :(

Comment: Hmm, I don't understand... What do you mean that you will receive already modified data? I meant sth like $message->from($ourMessage->getSwiftMessage()->getFrom());. Yes, it's a hassle so I'd first think if I really need to use my own message object in the first place. What you're trying to do is not a standard thing and in 99% cases standard usage of Mailer should be enough. So either you have some edge case or just trying to misuse the Mailer :)

Comment: And if the Illuminate\Mailer logic is not what you need you can always use SwiftMailer directly. No need to rewrite Mailer's logic if you can just skip it when it doesn't do what you need. Anyway, please elaborate on why standard behaviour is not ok for you and there might be a bettere way